# Set value in array to key in object reduce/return value inside object

Tags: javascript, recursion, reduce

The following should put out "Yuval"

```
console.log(pathFind(["book", "author", "name"], {
  book: {
    author: {
      name: "Yuval"
    }
  }
}));
```

I've tried writing this function but it keeps returning `undefined`:

```
function pathFind(path, object) {
  return path.reduce((accumulator, name) => {
    if(accumulator && accumulator[name] != typeof 'object') {
      accumulator[name]
    } else {
      undefined, object
    }
  })
}
```

What am I missing? (a typo?)

Is there a way to use recursion inside this function in combination with reduce? (i.e how to approach recursion for this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var obj = {
      book: {
        author: {
          name: "Yuval"         
        }       
      }
 };
 var path = ["book", "author", "name"];
 function findPath(obj, path){
    if(path.length === 0) return obj;
    return findPath(obj[path[0]], path.slice(1));
}
console.log(findPath(obj,path));
```

Comment: That's great I really like the way you've implemented recursion
thing is I'd like to run the function (inside a console.log or not)
without hardcoding the values inside variables.
I'd rather use the placeholder and reduce the incoming values 
to one.

when I run it (without hardcoding the values inside variables)

I get a Type-error, path.slice is not a function

Comment: @newDev basically you want to directly pass argument to your function? it is working for that too, make sure you pass first argument as object and then path array.

Comment: Thanks!
this  worked for me -->>

function pathFind(path, object){
   if(path.length === 0) return object;
   return pathFind(path.slice(1), object[path[0]] );
}